# How to get inside docker container to see the mounted volume?

Tags: docker

I am trying to buld a simple docker file that has a debian image.
Also, I want to mount my local volume inside the docker container. 
The problem I have is that how do I get inside the container to see the volume mounted.

```
$docker run -d -it bash --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/app docker_test:latest
43db16a76d50f1da0f8589c9ec460080ccef40122c9bc54abad3230dbbfe7885
```

I believe this 43db16a.. is container id. Even I try to attach to this container id  I get an an error message. It says you cannot attach to  the stop container. What am I missing here.

It works if I do

```
docker run -d -it --name test_docker1 --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/,target=/app docker_test:latest
```

and then

```
docker attach 
d6bd3cc6dc667e742d0bb3c7fbec58935046c1bf7a2e0b6806d48817082c05be
```

Also, it works when I do

```
$docker run  --rm -ti   --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/,target=/app docker_test:latest
```

Comment: As I understand from your question, you want to mount your current working directory into the container.
First of all, with the option `-d` the container will start in the background. By running only the terminal and not a persisstant process, the container will stop after it starts.
In your case I would use docker volumes.
`docker run -it --name test_docker1 -v "$(pwd)":/app docker_latest:latest`

Comment: If you think you're having trouble with the container startup, one of the first things to try is just removing the `-d` option to make the container start in the foreground; you will get the actual container output rather than just the container ID.

Answer (score 1):

In another terminal do a `docker ps`, then look for the image you are looking for and copy the id, then do a `docker exec -ti <your-image> bash` there you have a bash terminal inside the container and you can check the mounted volume.

Answer (score 0):

First run the docker image

1. docker run -it -d -p 8080:8080 containers.xyz.com/abc/MyAppImage:684f32bfe7e4146278c5d6e189ac070595f82794

Pls Note down the Container image

2. docker exec -it container_name  /bin/sh

You will get inside running container.